# PATH variable cannot be modified in shell function

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have one common function called `SetEnv` in a file called `SetEnv`.

File `SetEnv`:

```
SetEnv()
{    
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
}
```

File `Script.sh`:

```
SetEnv

echo $PATH
```

While running `./Script.sh`, I cannot see the updated path.

Please help how to solve this.

Comment: That is not how you set an environmental variable. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you run a script from terminal, this doesn't run in the current shell terminal, but in a subshell. The variables, functions and aliases created in this subshell are only known to the particular bash session of that subshell. When that shell exits and the parent regains control, everything is cleaned up and all changes to the state of the shell made by the script, are forgotten.

To prevent this, you can source the script in the current shell terminal, using the following command:

```bsh
source Script.sh
```

or, simple:

```bsh
. Script.sh          #dot, space and the path to the script
```

Also, your `Script.sh` should look like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

source /path/to/SetEnv  #if you want that your script to know about 'SetEnv' function.

SetEnv

echo $PATH
```

More about: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html.